# go install does not add the binary under GOBIN when running as cloudinit userdata script

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am trying to install this package: github.com/czerwonk/bird_exporter
After installing golang like so:

```
    GO_VERSION=1.17.1
    curl -L https://golang.org/dl/go${GO_VERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz -o go${GO_VERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.17.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    mkdir /root/go
    export GOPATH=/root/go
    export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/go/bin:${GOPATH}/bin
    echo "export GOPATH=${GOPATH}" >> /root/.bashrc
    echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/go/bin:${GOPATH}/bin" >> /root/.bashrc
```

I install the package like so:

```
    BIRD_EXPORTER_VERSION=1.2.6
    go install github.com/czerwonk/bird_exporter@${BIRD_EXPORTER_VERSION}
```

When running all these commands on the EC2 instance manually, I end up with the package under the default `GOBIN` location:

```
    file /root/go/bin/bird_exporter 
    /root/go/bin/bird_exporter: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

When the same commands get executed by cloudinit in the userdata script, the packages get installed fine under `/root/go/pkg/` but there is nothing under `/root/go/bin/`.
The logs show the downloading of all packages fine:

```
go: downloading github.com/czerwonk/bird_exporter v0.0.0-20210702094413-c9985a3895a4
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_golang v1.11.0
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.6.0
go: downloading github.com/czerwonk/bird_socket v0.0.0-20190111125930-6c39d61f8853
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_model v0.2.0
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/common v0.29.0
go: downloading github.com/beorn7/perks v1.0.1
go: downloading github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.1
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.3
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/procfs v0.6.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210603081109-ebe580a85c40
go: downloading github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions v1.0.1
go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.26.0-rc.1
```

I would like to understand what the difference is for `go install` in these 2 scenarios so that I can have proper control over installing the package

P.S. `go get`, which is deprecated, has the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.
The reason for the confusion was the log output as it was hard to read, but eventually I found this:

```
build cache is required, but could not be located: GOCACHE is not defined and neither $XDG_CACHE_HOME nor $HOME are defined
```

`HOME` is not set when cloudinit runs. Golang apparently requires it to determine `GOCACHE`. I would expect this to be under `GOPATH`.

The solution is to also export `GOCACHE`:

```
export GOCACHE=/root/go/cache
```